# Is there a way to enable "Implicit Usings" feature when compiling code with .NET Compiler SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-code-analysis

The "[ImplicitUsings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings)" feature allows code to omit usings statements for standard namespaces. I need to analyze a random source file(s) for which I may not know an appropriate set of includes. In C# 10 a standard set of namespaces could be included implicitly, as described in the help topic. Is there a way to use the standard namespaces when creating a compilation?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

var sourceText = "class C{" +
    "public void M(){" +
    " Console.Write(123);" +
    "}}";
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceText);

var coreReferences =
    ((string)AppContext.GetData("TRUSTED_PLATFORM_ASSEMBLIES"))
    .Split(Path.PathSeparator)
    .Select(p => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(p));
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyAnalysis")
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
    .AddReferences(coreReferences)
    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

var diagnostics = compilation.GetDiagnostics();
Debug.Assert(diagnostics.Length == 0);
// diagnostics = "error CS0103: The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context"
```

To clarify the above example, I'm compiling the source in the sourceText variable. The diagnostics variable contains the error that Console does not exist. If I add "using System" in the sourceText above, the code compiles without the error. Is there a way to enable the Implicit Usings feature so that compilation resolves symbols from standard namespaces?

Comment: So your desire is to put an `<ItemGroup>` at or above the folder of you project?

Comment: `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` in your  csproj file then you get an auto generated file like at  `obj/Debug/net6.0,` and see a file titled `“ProjectName.GlobalUsings.g.cs”`

Comment: You can use the itemgroup then to add/remove `<ItemGroup>
  <Using Remove="System.Threading" />
  <Using Include="something.cool" />
</ItemGroup>`  this is WAY off the cuff here and not a thought out response to create an answer

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using a project file. This API allows compiling any code snippet and is used for code analysis. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not implicit usings, but you can add usings to your compilation externally by using the [`WithUsings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilationoptions.withusings?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0#microsoft-codeanalysis-csharp-csharpcompilationoptions-withusings(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))) method of the `CSharpCompilationOptions` class.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know which usings are needed ahead of time, as I need to analyze a random piece of code or a class.

Comment: Then give up, if you don't know what you need ahead of time and won't write proper `using`s in code, then you can't compile. Was your hope that the standard "implicit usings" would somehow guess what you need? They don't, they're just a list of usings. You can see the full list [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/), and you can feed it by hand using the API I listed above.

Comment: Thanks for the link on implicit usings

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions I'm pursuing a possible solution by creating a global usings file(s) corresponding to specific known SDK(s). Will probably look up SDK in the project file or use a default. For example, for Microsoft.NET.Sdk I created the following file (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.usings.cs):

```
global using System;
global using System.Collections.Generic;
global using System.IO;
global using System.Linq;
global using System.Net.Http;
global using System.Threading;
global using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

There is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives) describing default namespaces for standard SDK(s). Then I can load it and parse as an additional syntax tree getting rid of the compilation error. There are warnings about unnecessary using directives. The complete code is this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

var sourceText = "class C{" +
    "public void M(){" +
    " Console.Write(123);" +
    "}}";
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceText);

var globalUsings = File.ReadAllText("Microsoft.NET.Sdk.usings.cs");
var usingsTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(globalUsings);

var coreReferences =
    ((string)AppContext.GetData("TRUSTED_PLATFORM_ASSEMBLIES"))
    .Split(Path.PathSeparator)
    .Select(p => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(p));
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyAnalysis")
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
    .AddReferences(coreReferences)
    .AddSyntaxTrees(usingsTree, syntaxTree);

var diagnostics = compilation.GetDiagnostics();
Debug.Assert(!diagnostics.Any(d => d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error));
```